# How to check if user logged in using React and Embedded RuBy (erb)?

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I am working on the task where I should allow the user to perform some actions if it logged in and in case if it's not I should redirect the user to the Login page.

The project itself is built using Ruby on Rails, Reactjs. It uses embedded ruby (erb) to display the Login button. And for rendering components themselves it uses React.

My problem is that even after the user logged in, I don't understand how I can create a condition that checks if the user is logged in or not in my React component.

**Login template: (application.html.erb)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
    <title>Kittynews</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="box header">
      <div class="home">
        <%= link_to 'Home', root_path %>
      </div>
      <div class="session">
        <% if user_signed_in? %>
          <span>Hi <%= current_user.name %>,</span>
          <%= link_to 'Logout', destroy_user_session_path, data: { method: :delete } %>
        <% else %>
          <%= link_to 'Login', new_user_session_path %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </header>
    <% if alert.present? || notice.present? %>
      <div class="notice">
        <%= alert || notice %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <section class="content">
      <%= yield %>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

The React component where I need to add a condition that will check: if the button was clicked by the logged-in user - it should upvote the reviews. If the user is not logged in - it should redirect him to the Login Page

```
import * as React from 'react';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import { useQuery } from 'react-apollo';
import renderComponent from './utils/renderComponent';

const QUERY = gql`
  query PostsPage {
    viewer {
      id
    }
    ReviewsAll {
      id
      title
      tagline
      url
      commentsCount
      votes
    }
  }
`;

function upVote(review) {
  review.votes += 1;
}

function ReviewsIndex() {
  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(QUERY);
  
  if (loading) return 'Loading...';
  if (error) return `Error! ${error.message}`;

  return (
    <div className="container">
      {console.log(data.reviewsAll)}
      {data.reviewsAll.map((review) => (
        <article className="review" key={review.id}>
          <h2>
            <a href={`/reviews/${review.id}`}>{review.title}</a>
          </h2>
          <div className="myUrl">
            <a href={review.url}>{review.url}</a>
          </div>
          <div className="tagline">{review.tagline}</div>
          <footer>
            <button onClick={() => upVote(review)}> {review.votes} </button>
          </footer>
        </article>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

renderComponent(ReviewsIndex);
```

I am new to React and in Ruby and worked with Agular/Flask before.
Would much appreciate your support!

Answer (score 0):

try devise gem it solves login/signup problems in rails.

https://rubygems.org/gems/devise

to see how to install and use it,I refer
[codemy-Yotube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9K5YvsrKBRk&list=PLCC34OHNcOtrk3BDsfZwf4GattdLoKCOF&index=6)